# WPF ScrollView scroller reset

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scroll, scrollview

Is there any way to make ScrollView scroller back to start position using code ? For example when you press button ...

From:
[image: asd]

To:
[image: asd2]

XAML Code:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="tempimas" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="795">
            <Canvas Name="zem" Height="1000" Width="Auto">
                <Image Name="pav_kelias" />
                <Image Name="car1" Height="100" Width="200"/>
            </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scroll to top use **tempimas.ScrollToTop();** in click event of button